# Overriding property getter from accessor decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator, propertydescriptor

I have some code like this:

```js
function changeProperty(prototype: Object, propertyKey: string) {
  Object.defineProperty(prototype, 'extra', {
    get: () => 'added'
  });

  const existing = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, propertyKey);
  Object.defineProperty(prototype, propertyKey, {
    get: () => 'pass'
  });
}

class Test {
  @changeProperty
  get original() { return 'fail'}
}

// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
const x = new Test() as any;
appDiv.innerHTML = `original: ${x.original}<br/>extra: ${x.extra}`;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-j8s1bq

I observe that the `extra` property is added successfully, but I am unable to override/overwrite/delete the existing property.

I cannot figure out the explanation for why this is the case.

If I use a class decorator, I am able to use the same technique to override getters.

Comment: Shouldn't the decorator `return` the new descriptor?

Comment: According to the documentation and typings, no. Not for property/accessor decorators

Comment: Apparently I messed up reading the docs, which distinguish between property decorators (applied to a plain field), and accessor decorators. difference being, there's a 3rd parameter that I missed containing the current property descriptor

Answer (score 1):

What I missed is that for **accessor** decorators, you have a `PropertyDescriptor` passed in as the third argument.

it is sufficient to do the following:

```js
propertyDescriptor.get = () => 'new value';
```